# How to have an image go through many functions determined by probability weights?

Tags: python, random, python-imaging-library, probability, image-augmentation

I have a logo. What I am doing now is I am setting probability weights for all of these functions and the logo goes to only one of them at a time depending on its probability value.  This is my code:

```
augmentation_func = [(random_rotation, [brand_logo]),
                             (blurring, [brand_logo]),
                             (compression, [brand_logo]),
                             (portion_covering, [brand_logo, brand_logo_width, brand_logo_height]),
                             (perspective_transform, [logo_image, brand_logo_width, brand_logo_height]),
                             (overlaying, [logo_path]),
                             (logo_background, [logo_path])]

        (augs, args), = random.choices(augmentation_func, weights=[10,5,15,20,20,15,15])

        new_logo = random_resize(augs(*args), gameplay)
```

However, this isn't sufficient. The logo should be able to go through multiple functions. For example. A logo could potentially go through `random_rotation()`, `perspective_transformation()` and `overlaying()`. Whether it will go through a function or not should depend on its probability weight. This is my idea:

[image]

How can I adjust my code so that the logo goes through many transformation functions depending on the weights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the chance that each operation occurs independent of the others? Then `random.choice()` is not the correct solution, since it chooses only one item. Rather, for each item, choose it with its corresponding probability. For example:

```
if random.randrange(0, 100) < 10:
    # Crop the image (in place) at a 10% chance.
    # The chance of cropping is independent
    # of the chances of any other operation.
    brand_logo = cropping(brand_logo)
    
if random.randrange(0, 100) < 15:
    # Rotate the image (in place) at a 15% chance.
    # The chance of rotating is independent
    # of the chances of any other operation.
    brand_logo = rotating(brand_logo)
```

Comment: So in your logic, you are taking the original image and doing both cropping and rotating. What I need is first do cropping (if probability permits) and then do rotating on the cropped image (if probability permits)

Comment: That is how the example works: the `cropping()` call is done at a 10% chance, and then, independently, the `rotating()` call is done at a 15% chance.  I will make this answer clearer.

Comment: So if cropping happens, does the output of cropping get sent to rotating?

Comment: Yes it does.  This is not necessarily clear from the example, but assume the code modifies `brand_logo` in place.

Comment: It would do so if you reassigned `brand_logo = cropping(brand_logo)` like this..

Comment: Edited.  However, my main point is that you should "roll" for each operation separately, rather than "draw one of them out of a hat", so to speak.